# Fail2ban not using sender in jail.conf

Tags: email, relay, postfix-mta, fail2ban

I am trying to change the sender of Fail2ban email notifications to a separate domain.

Inside  `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` I specify:

```
sender = no-reply@externaldomain.com
mta = mail
```

However, when I restart the service, emails are still being sent from `root@domain.com`

I am using Postfix and configured the relay to use an external domain correctly. Is there anything else I am missing in Fail2ban options?

Comment: Here is a jail I have setup for SSH
`[ssh-iptables]

enabled  = true
filter   = sshd
action   = iptables[name=SSH, port=ssh, protocol=tcp]
           sendmail-buffered[name=SSH, dest=administrator@domain.com, sender=fail2ban@domain.com, sendername="Fail2Ban"]
logpath  = /var/log/secure
maxretry = 5
bantime  = 604800
`

Answer (score 2):

## Summary

Because you are using `mta = mail`, the variable `sender` is not used (by default). You must change some config(s) to make the command use the `sender` variable.

If you are like me, you read an article like [How To Protect an Nginx Server with Fail2Ban on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04), which mentions using `sendername = Fail2BanAlerts`. Perhaps `sendername` was used in the default actions in past versions, but at least with my version, v0.11.1, neither `sender` nor `sendername` are used by the `mail` actions (they ARE used by the `sendmail-*` actions, e.g. `sendmail-whois-lines.conf`). You can change the actions to use the variables, or hard-code values in the actions.

## Detail

How to actually send an email is specified (in your case, because you specified `mta = mail`) in one of the files starting with `mail` in the `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/` dir:

- `mail-buffered.conf`
- `mail-whois-common.conf`
- `mail-whois-lines.conf`
- `mail-whois.conf`
- `mail.conf`

You didn't say what your `action` is set to, but let's assume for example that it's configured like this: `action = %(action_mwl)s`.

In your jail file (e.g. `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`), it has something like this:

```
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Note that **`%(mta)s-whois-lines`** part at the start of the second line. The `%(mta)s` is python string interpolation with the `mta` variable, so it becomes `mail-whois-lines`. So, you need to edit the file `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/mail-whois-lines.conf`.

In the file `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/mail-whois-lines.conf`, there's this:

```
mailcmd = mail -s
```

You could hard-code some values here. The mail command (Postfix) needs to use `-a` to specify headers like `From:`. So you could do this:

```
mailcmd = mail -a "From: My Name <myemail@example.com>" -s
```

Or you could use the `sender` variable like this:

```
mailcmd = mail -a "From: <sender>" -s
```

## Extra credit: use `sendername` variable

If you have this in your `jail.local`:

```
sendername = My Name
```

How do you use that? We first need to update (the second line only of) where we set `action_mwl`. You can already see that `sender` is being passed there. Let's add `sendername`.

```
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
             %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, sendername="%(sendername)s", sender="%(sender)s", dest="%(destemail)s", logpath="%(logpath)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Then use it in the `action.d/mail-whois-lines.conf`:

```
mailcmd = mail -a "From: <sendername> <<sender>>" -s
```

We must use double angle brackets around `sender` because variables require the angle brackets, and the `From` header itself needs the angle brackets around the email address (if a From name is used).